# install maven on mac

Tags: bash, macos, maven-3

i'm trying to install maven on my mac first i downloaded apache-maven-3.3.9 and then i entered this code on my bash:

```
export M2_HOME=$(/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9)
```

and

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/sabrine/ant/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin:
```

but it doesn't work i got(i tried with **mvn -v**)

```
-bash: mvn: command not found
```

where is the problem? what should i do?

Comment: [`brew`](http://brew.sh/) `install maven`?

Comment: **thank you!** it works now
that's all? is there any thing to add?

Comment: No, that's it; use home brew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add `$(` `)` around the paths, just use:

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9
```

Followed by yours:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/sabrine/ant/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin:
```

The above assumes that your maven installation is in /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9, and `ls -ld /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9` gives non-error output.

Answer (score 3):

Please follow below steps on terminal

Create bash profile (will be created under home folder and will be hidden file)

```
$ touch .bash_profile
```

Edit bash profile in editor and put next 2 commands in file, save file.

```
 export M2_HOME=/Users/srajp/apache-maven-3.5.3

 export PATH=$PATH:/Users/srajp/apache-maven-3.5.3/bin
```

Then check Maven version

```
$ mvn --version
```

If needed please see detailed steps on my blog on [How to install Maven on MAC OS?](http://iphoneexample.blogspot.com/2018/04/how-to-install-maven-on-mac-os-globally.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can install maven on mac using this command.

```
brew install maven
```