# How to ensure maven is installed in mac

Tags: java, apache, maven, installation

I'm trying to install [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/index.html) in my Mac system (MacOS: High Siera, Version: 10.13.3).

I followed all steps from this document: [Installing Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)

1. Donloaded tar file from a link: [apache-maven-3.5.2-bin.tar.gz](http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.5.2/binaries/apache-maven-3.5.2-bin.tar.gz) extracted in same directory
2. `echo $JAVA_HOME /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home`
3. `export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin:$PATH`

All command executed without any error. Even tried using this also: [Installation of the Maven command line tools](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheMaven/article.html).

But still system show an error when I try execute `mvn` command:

> -bash: mvn: command not found

[image]

How can I ensure, whether maven is properly installed in my system or not? Or my question can be: How to install maven in macOS?

I tried solutions from following SO questions also but nothing works:

- [install maven on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295609/install-maven-on-mac)
- [Installing maven 3.0.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730375/installing-maven-3-0-4)
- [Maven Install on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826881/maven-install-on-mac-os-x?rq=1) (I can't use brew, most upvoted solution here)

Comment: Directory from step 1. should be the same as in step 3. Does the directory /opt/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin actually exists?

Comment: @user158037 - No, I think no.. Let me check it...

Comment: You have to download it manually unpack it to an appropriate location for example `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.5.3` and add the `bin` directory of this to `PATH` ..to do that permanently add this setup to `.bashrc_profile`...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue before and resolved it by the following steps

1: Down load Maven [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

2: Open Terminal

3: Type cd ~/

4: Type touch .bash_profile

5: Type open -e .bash_profile to open .bash_profile in TextEdit

6: Type the following in the TextEdit

> export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/**jdkx.x.x_xxx.jdk**/Contents/Home
>
> export M2_HOME=/User/**username/[Your file location]**/apache-maven-3.6.0/
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
>
> alias mvn='$M2_HOME/bin/mvn'

- jdkx.x.x_xxx.jdk : Your java version
- username: Your username

7: Save the file

8: Type source .bash_profile

9: Type mvn -version

And you will see the following message:

> Apache Maven 3.1.1
> Maven home: /Users/username/Maven/apache-maven-3.1.1
> Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
> Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
> Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
> OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

for `how to install maven in mac` and `how to make it take effect immediately` and `how to make sure maven installed correctly`,  please refer my answer in  [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826881/maven-install-on-mac-os-x/59693781#59693781).

In short, all step of manual install is:

1. download binary (latest [apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip](https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip)) from [official site](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
2. uncompress (apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip) it to somewhere (/Users/crifan/dev/dev_tool/java/maven)
3. add the `bin path of maven` (/Users/crifan/dev/dev_tool/java/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin) into `PATH`

normally is:

- edit your start script (`.bashrc` / `.zshrc` / ...)

  - `vi ~/.bashrc`
- add following config into it

  - `export PATH=/Users/crifan/dev/dev_tool/java/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:$PATH`
- make it take effect (right now, in current console)

  - `source ~/.bashrc`
- verify can found maven

  - `which mvn`
- and check its version

  - `mvn --version`

example output:

```sh
➜  bin pwd
/Users/crifan/dev/dev_tool/java/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
➜  bin ll
total 64
-rw-r--r--@ 1 crifan  staff   228B 11  7 12:32 m2.conf
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 crifan  staff   5.6K 11  7 12:32 mvn
-rw-r--r--@ 1 crifan  staff   6.2K 11  7 12:32 mvn.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 crifan  staff   1.5K 11  7 12:32 mvnDebug
-rw-r--r--@ 1 crifan  staff   1.6K 11  7 12:32 mvnDebug.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 crifan  staff   1.5K 11  7 12:32 mvnyjp
➜  bin vi ~/.bashrc
➜  bin source ~/.bashrc
➜  bin echo $PATH
/Users/crifan/dev/dev_tool/java/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:xxx
➜  bin which mvn
/Users/crifan/dev/dev_tool/java/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn
➜  bin mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /Users/crifan/dev/dev_tool/java/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 1.8.0_112, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

for detailed info please refer my (Chinese) post: [【已解决】Mac中安装Gradle](http://www.crifan.com/mac_install_gradle)

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue. Somehow I was able to resolve this. Sharing steps :

Perquisite is, to have maven and java downloaded in your system. If these don't exist than, download, extract and follow below steps.

Open .bash_profile

**sudo vi .bash_profile**

Add these contents ( make sure you point to correct locations as your system, in below example I have used installation directories of my machine)

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME

M2_HOME=/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.0
export M2_HOME

export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${M2_HOME}/bin
export PATH
```

save and exit.

```
source .bash_profile
```

fire mvn -version

you will be able to get the below output, which implies maven is installed.

```
mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-25T00:11:47+05:30)
Maven home: /Applications/apache-maven-3.6.0
Java version: 1.8.0_191, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: I am seeing [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. error when I run any mvn command. What should I do?